# Conformally invariant vector field

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory, vector-fields

Considering the action in this post: [Metric field equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/587638/metric-field-equations) and the conformal transformation:   $\space \hat g_{\mu\nu}=e^{2 \sigma(x)} g_{\mu\nu}$ , what conditions must we impose on $A_\mu$ such that it becomes a conformally invariant vector field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^{\mu}$ should be a [conformal Killing vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_Killing_vector_field). Various equivalent conditions are listed on Wikipedia.

Comment: This means that the Lie derivative of the metric, along $A$, should be: $\mathfrak{L}_A(g_{\mu\nu})=e^{2 \sigma(x)} g_{\mu\nu}$ which then leads to: $A_{\mu ; \nu}+A_{\nu ; \mu}=e^{2 \sigma(x)} g_{\mu\nu}$ , correct?

Comment: What about a conformal vector field without conformal anomaly? Are there any instances?(extending the discussion from classical field theory to QFT)